# Expo app system logs not showing console logs

Tags: reactjs, expo

I'm building an application with an expo, and I'm finding that I can't rely on Expo Go because it injects some configuration that breaks my app. I can build and run my app without Expo Go, but I can't figure out how to view the logs of the non-expo-go app.

Here's some code that does some logging:

```
      const appId = Constants.manifest.facebookAppId;
      console.log({ appId });
      const permissions = ["public_profile", "email"];
      await Facebook.initializeAsync({ appId, appName: "Tripvector" });
      const results = await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync({
        permissions,
      });
      console.log({ results });
```

When I run my app through expo go, I see the output of `appId` and `results.`

Then, I built my application with `expo build: ios,` downloaded the tarball, extracted it, and installed the removed application into my simulator.

I opened up this newly installed application, and it seems to work generally, but I can't figure out how to view the logs of this application.

I've tried looking at the system logs in the simulator with `cmd + /,` but I only see the following:

```
May 21 11:28:56 forrestry syslogd[96118]: --- syslogd restarted ---
May 21 11:28:56 forrestry syslogd[96118]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.contacts.ContactsAutocomplete" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
May 21 11:28:56 forrestry syslogd[96118]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.clouddocs" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
May 22 08:57:02 forrestry syslogd[44981]: --- syslogd restarted ---
May 22 08:57:02 forrestry syslogd[44981]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.contacts.ContactsAutocomplete" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
May 22 08:57:02 forrestry syslogd[44981]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.clouddocs" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
```

I've also tried running `tail -f ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/15DF07B0-EF12-4228-BBB4-BE0EC3BB7F7D/system.log`, but that gives the same result. I've also tried using the safari simulator feature, but that only shows Expo Go

[Here's an image of my Safari > Develop feature menu (which doesn't embed because I'm new to StackOverflow)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoF9i.png)

How can I view the `console.log` output of an expo app that has been built with `expo build` and then installed into an iOS simulator?